# AngularJS WebAPI2 how Add multipart/form-data

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I am uploading file from AngularJS(client side) to API2). When ever I add multipart/form-data service layer shows me error.
unsupported media type.

Comment: This needs a lot more information

Comment: Try adding the header Content-Type = application/json

Comment: my one application on AngularJS (plain without visual studio) and I want to upload file from the API2(Asp.net). I tried a lot of options but fail.

Comment: thanks for the response. I was using method FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter() and UploadMultipartMediaTypeFormatter(). When I remove them then API accept multipart/form-data but still don't know the reason behind it. I was just hit and try case for me.